# ssh and scp redirects to my own server

Tags: ssh, scp

recently I've installed a new server, and got a lot of problems with the ssh access.

Now, when I try to scp from server A ( old, Debian 7.1 ) to B ( new, Debian 7.1 ), or when I try to ssh from A to B, I get logged in A or the scp copy I make end in the origin, in A.

Also, I can't get logged through ssh from B to A.

Someone has faced this problem before ? As server A is an OVH server and server B is a Kimsufi server ( both companies belong to OVH ), I think it could be some problem of IP or network related. Their primary ip start with the same sequence 91.121.xx.xx ( as usual in OVH ).

If it's there some log that could help, I can post it. The ssh log seems normal, including the correct IP, the only problem is I get logged to the server I'm already.

[EDIT] Finally I've found where the problem was. I've configured one subdomain in the server A with the IP of the server B, with virtualmin, and that rendered a network interface in the A server with the IP of the B server. After correcting this situation, both ping and ssh worked again. I suspected this after realizing that ping worked fine for all IPs but the one in my other server.

Answer (score 0):

Try ping server A from B and when successful

- look into /var/log/auth.log on server A
- try ssh -v

In addition you can check iptables for some forgotten drop/reject rule on ssh port.

Comment: thanks, @Scypi, playing with ping pointed me out to the problem. I've updated my question with the correct solution, it was my fault as I misconfigured a subdomain with the other server's IP.